# Appending Excel cell values into XML with Java

Tags: java, xml, excel

I have been trying to append Excel values into some specific xml nodes with loops.

The code I am using now:

```
 public ExcelReaderAndWriter(String inputFileName,String outputFileName) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)


    try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(inputFileName))) {



        // Getting the Sheet at index zero
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("XSL_RULES");

        // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        //obtain a rowIterator and columnIterator and iterate over them
        System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator\n");

        Iterator <Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            // Now let's iterate over the columns of the current row
            Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            if (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);

                DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
                try {
                    docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
                Element rootElement = doc.createElement("ROOT");
                doc.appendChild(rootElement);
                // TOMORROW CREATE A LOOP TO GET ALL THE FILES and NODES.

                for (int k = 1; k <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); k++) {
                    Element xslt_rule = doc.createElement("RULES");

                        xslt_rule.setAttribute("ATTR1"sheet.getRow (k).getCell (0).getStringCellValue ());
                        xslt_rule.setAttribute("ATTR2", sheet.getRow (k).getCell (1).getStringCellValue ());
                        xslt_rule.setAttribute("ATTR3", sheet.getRow (k).getCell (2).getStringCellValue ());

                    }

                    xslt_rule.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(sheet.getRow (k).getCell (28).getStringCellValue ());
                    rootElement.appendChild(xslt_rule);


                }
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = null;

                try

                {
                    transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e)

                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(outputFileName));


                try {
                    transformer.transform(source, result);
                } catch (TransformerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            try {
                workbook.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }


}
```

So this code works "somehow" but I have problems to get each element recursively. When I execute it, It creates the file up to some place (usually the end of the file and the last cell values.

Imagine that this is our simple excel example:

```
 1  Example1  Example5  Example9   Value1
 2  Example2  Example6  Example10  Value2
 3  Example3  Example7  Example11  Value3
 4  Example4  Example8  Example12  Value4
```

I want to map these elements as my desire output into XML:

```
<ROOT>
  <RULES ATTR1="Example1" ATTR2="Example5" ATTR3="Example9>Value1</RULES>
  <RULES ATTR1="Example2" ATTR2="Example6" ATTR3="Example10>Value2</RULES>
  <RULES ATTR1="Example3" ATTR2="Example7" ATTR3="Example11>Value3</RULES>
  <RULES ATTR1="Example4" ATTR2="Example8" ATTR3="Example12>Value4</RULES>
</ROOT>
```

I think I made a mistake in While loop as well because it never stops with one execution, after several times the loops stops at the end.

Where is the mistake here and how can I imrove this in better and cleaner way? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I found the solution and edited the code. It is working.

The problem was my for loop, that I could not find how to count the row numbers and get the numbers based on that loop. It was about whole sheet and row numbers. It wasnt so hard after all. Hope it helps to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution is :

```
public ExcelReaderAndWriter(String inputFileName,String outputFileName) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

// Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)


try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(inputFileName))) {



    // Getting the Sheet at index zero
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("XSL_RULES");

    // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

    //obtain a rowIterator and columnIterator and iterate over them
    System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator\n");

    Iterator <Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        // Now let's iterate over the columns of the current row
        Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        if (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);

            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
            try {
                docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("ROOT");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);
            // TOMORROW CREATE A LOOP TO GET ALL THE FILES and NODES.

            for (int k = 1; k <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); k++) {
                Element xslt_rule = doc.createElement("RULES");

                    xslt_rule.setAttribute("ATTR1"sheet.getRow (k).getCell (0).getStringCellValue ());
                    xslt_rule.setAttribute("ATTR2", sheet.getRow (k).getCell (1).getStringCellValue ());
                    xslt_rule.setAttribute("ATTR3", sheet.getRow (k).getCell (2).getStringCellValue ());

                }

                xslt_rule.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(sheet.getRow (k).getCell (28).getStringCellValue ());
                rootElement.appendChild(xslt_rule);


            }
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = null;

            try

            {
                transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e)

            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(outputFileName));


            try {
                transformer.transform(source, result);
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        try {
            workbook.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}